# How can I get the account that is calling a function using Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm trying to make a test application, where accounts can only call a function once. Is this possible? All I need is a way to get the account/address that is calling my function, AKA the "from" part.

Answer (score 0):

If calling from an account, you use `msg.sender`. If calling from a contract, you can look at `tx.origin`.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin